# Select and display value from each new "select option" created for table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I could not find a solution so far for the following issue. If anyone can help me in this, I will be very happy.

I have a simple table with 1 select box and one text box. I am adding table rows with jQuery script add button. Similarly there is delete option.

My target is to display selected names in each row. But when I am adding rows and then selecting the "select option", the name changes for every row. That's not intended here.

Here is fiddle link for testing - 
https://jsfiddle.net/rmse9nw3/

```
<table id="datagrid" class="display table1">
```

```
  <th>Employee Code</th>
  <th>Employee Name</th>
```

```
<tr id="row1">
    <td > 
    <select name="empid" class="dropdn">
        <option>Please select...</option>
        <option>Jhon Doe</option>
        <option>George Antony</option>
        <option>David Blare</option>
        <option>Kene Roy</option>
    </select> 

    </td>

    <td>
        <input type='text' readonly name="name" size="20" class="name" value=""/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="addRow" class="add" value='Add'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="removeRow" class="removeRow" value='Delete'/>
    </td>
```

And jQuery is -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click','#datagrid .add',function () {

           var row=$(this).closest('tr');
           var clone = row.clone();
           var tr= clone.closest('tr');
           tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
           $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
           var $span=$("#datagrid tr");
           $span.attr('id',function (index) {
           return 'row' + index;

        });

    });

    $(document).on('click','#datagrid .removeRow',function () {
        if ($('#datagrid .add').length > 1) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }

    });

}); 

var dropDown = ".dropdn";
var empName = ".name";

$(document).on("change",(dropDown),function(e){

    var value = $.trim($(this).val());

    $(empName).val(value);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `.name`, will select all the field in the document with class attribute equals to `name`, so when you set a new value to it, it will change every fields `.name`.

To change only the "right" name, you could modify the following line:

```
$(empName).val(value);
```

to

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(empName).val(value);
```

in order to get only the input field `name` in the same `tr` of the `select` element.

See following snippets (where I modify just the above line), please:

```js
(function($) {
 // always strict mode on
 // cannot use undefined vars on strict mode
 "use strict";

 $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $(document).on('click','#datagrid .add',function () {
 
      var row=$(this).closest('tr');
      var clone = row.clone();
      var tr= clone.closest('tr');
      tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
      $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
      var $span=$("#datagrid tr");
      $span.attr('id',function (index) {
      return 'row' + index;
     
   });
   
  });
  
  $(document).on('click','#datagrid .removeRow',function () {
   if ($('#datagrid .add').length > 1) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   }
   
  });
  
 }); 

 var dropDown = ".dropdn";
 var empName = ".name";
 
    $(document).on("change",(dropDown),function(e){
  
  var value = $.trim($(this).val());
  
    //Change this line:
 //$(empName).val(value);
    //To:
    $(this).closest('tr').find(empName).val(value);
  
 }); 
 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datagrid" class="display table1">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Employee Code</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="dataTable">

    <tr id="row1">
        <td > 
        <select name="empid" class="dropdn">
            <option>Please select...</option>
            <option>Jhon Doe</option>
            <option>George Antony</option>
            <option>David Blare</option>
            <option>Kene Roy</option>
        </select> 
       
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type='text' readonly name="name" size="20" class="name" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="addRow" class="add" value='Add'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="removeRow" class="removeRow" value='Delete'/>
        </td>
        
  </tr>
                
</tbody>

</table>
```

I hope it was clear, bye.

**Updated, answer to new question, how to add options dinamically**:

```js
$.each([
  { id : 1, name : "Jhon Doe"},
  { id : 2, name : "George Antony"},
  { id : 3, name : "David Blare"},
  { id : 4, name : "Kene Roy"}
], function( index, value ) {
    $('#empid').append($('<option>',
    {
        value: value["id"],
        text : value["name"]
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="empid" class="dropdn">
    <option>Please select...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro. Btw, can I fetch data for text field from variables? Example, now we are getting values for each "dropdn". But if I store some data in individual variables, like `var name1 = "Jhon Doe"` etc. Please let me know if it's understandable to you.

Comment: I added a little example to show you how to add elements to select input using jQuery, anyway consider to ask a new question. Bye

Answer (score 2):

You can use :last pseudo-selector to select the last cloned element having class name 'name',

```
var dropDown = ".dropdn";
var empName = ".name:last";//select last element having classname named 'name'

$(document).on("change",(dropDown),function(e){

    var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    $(empName).val(value);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```js
(function($) {
 // always strict mode on
 // cannot use undefined vars on strict mode
 "use strict";

 $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $(document).on('click','#datagrid .add',function () {
 
      var row=$(this).closest('tr');
      var clone = row.clone();
      var tr= clone.closest('tr');
      tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
      $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
      var $span=$("#datagrid tr");
      $span.attr('id',function (index) {
      return 'row' + index;
     
   });
   
  });
  
  $(document).on('click','#datagrid .removeRow',function () {
   if ($('#datagrid .add').length > 1) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   }
   
  });
  
 }); 

 var dropDown = ".dropdn";
 var empName = ".name";
 
    $(document).on("change",(dropDown),function(e){
  
  var value = $.trim($(this).val());
  
  $(this).parent().next().find(".name").val(value);
  
 }); 
 
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datagrid" class="display table1">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Employee Code</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="dataTable">

    <tr id="row1">
        <td > 
        <select name="empid" class="dropdn">
            <option>Please select...</option>
            <option>Jhon Doe</option>
            <option>George Antony</option>
            <option>David Blare</option>
            <option>Kene Roy</option>
        </select> 
       
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type='text' readonly name="name" size="20" class="name" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="addRow" class="add" value='Add'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="removeRow" class="removeRow" value='Delete'/>
        </td>
        
  </tr>
                
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

having class .name in not working properly. Your selection is applied to all elements under that class. You need to target that input only. check this:

```
$(document).on("change",(dropDown),function(e){

  var value = $.trim($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).parent().parent());
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.name').val(value);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/rmse9nw3/3/

Actually, when an option was selected from the dropdown, you were selecting all the `<input>` and then changing its value. What I did is, when an option was selected then move to the closest `tr` then find the `<input>` inside that `<tr>` and change its value and voila, its done :)